# Magento 2 Make Not Required field on registration Page

Tags: magento2, registration, field, required

I have enabled address field on Customer registration page and everything is working fine and fields street address,city,state,country and zip all are now appearing on page.

When I create an account these fields are required but I want to Make it **Not required** as per requirement.

I have checked admin settings but not found any option to make it **Not required**.
Please let me know what can I do without affecting other parts.

Comment: which field and which page ??

Comment: Check this link https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-validate-form-magento-2.html

Comment: @RkRathod,I already mentioned in question,that is registration page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make it optional to add the address. It can be done by using the collapsible jquery widget. Keep the fields disabled by default and once the collapsible is expanded then enable all fields. This way you can avoid posting of the fields and if the fields are missing then the form will simply act similar to the original registration.